# display full path for selected item in mvcsitemap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcsitemapprovider

i have been using mvcsitemap from codeplex. it's great but i am struggling with how to display the full path in the breadcrumb for the 3rd level item below in my sitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="About Us" controller="AboutUs" action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Team" action="team">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="John Smith" action="john-smith" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

at the moment the "team" and "john smith" actions live in the "about us" controller. both actions have their own separate views. the problem is when i render the sitemap to a menu it shows the path to the "john smith" page as "about-us/john-smith, but i want it to display as "about-us/team/john-smith" (just like the visual hierarchy in the sitemap)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a route for TeamController.john-smith then.

Comment: but the controller is called "AboutUs" and the actions are "Team" and "John Smith".

Comment: Can you post your route table?